# Received Memory warning in iPad 1 but working fine in iPad 2 & 3

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management

Recently i have updated my app to support iOS 7.0 but now my app is not working in iPad 1(iOS 5.1.1) and its working fine in iPad 2(iOS 6.1.3) and iPad 3(iOS 7.0).

Right now i am running my app with instruments to improve performance but i am not able to understand that same code not generating memory in iPad 2 & 3 and create problem in iPad 1 only. so whenever i modified code, i need to check in all 3 devices and some of the code is not working in iPad 2(iOS 6.1.3)

I have implemented custom tabbar controller to match iOS 7.0 design in iOS 6 & 5. i am planning to modify to remove custom tababr and implement UITabBarController instead of that.

Let me know is there any easy solution for that or any alternative to solve this problem. do i need to reinstall iOS in iPad 1 or is there any hardware related problem with my iPad 1?

Comment: I think you could reasonably bet that if it works on iPad1, it'll work well on the later devices. iPad1 only has 256MB of memory, some of which is used by the OS. . Take a look at Andrews Brown Braun's answer. . . Look for any loops where you allocate heavy objects to a whole collection. Look for places you can use an autoreleasepool. Run the code using the leaks tool in instruments (leaks is nice - shows both allocations/usage and leaks (if any)). Try to hang on to your old devices for testing - they will help identify problems earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that iPad 1 has less memory than iPad2 or iPad3 so memory warning is provoked before. If you want to run your App in iPad 1 you need to improve your memory management. I recommend you that you watch the "Fixing Memory Issue" in https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/.

Good luck!